# Spring 4 MVC Locale changed but JSP does not respond for this

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

This is my configuration files:

Initializer:

```
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        ctx.register(ApplicationConfig.class);

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));
        servletContext.setInitParameter("defaultHtmlEscape", "true");
        servletContext.addListener(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
        servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic fr = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter",
                new CharacterEncodingFilter());
        fr.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        fr.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");

        servletContext.addFilter("securityFilter", new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"))
                .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME,
                new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.setAsyncSupported(true);

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);
    }

    public Filter[] getServletFilters() {

        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

        return new Filter[]{characterEncodingFilter, new DelegatingFilterProxy()};
    }

}
```

ApplicationConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.example.*")
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Charset UTF8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        OpenSessionInViewInterceptor sessionInViewInterceptor = new OpenSessionInViewInterceptor();
        sessionInViewInterceptor.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        registry.addWebRequestInterceptor(sessionInViewInterceptor);
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource ret = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        ret.setBasenames("classpath:messages", "classpath:labels", "classpath:exceptions");
        ret.setDefaultEncoding(UTF8.name());
        return ret;
    }

//    @Bean
//    public SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver() {
//        // TODO locale
//        Locale ruLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("ru").build();
//        SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
//        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(ruLocale);
//        return localeResolver;
//    }

    @Bean
    public CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        CookieLocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        cookieLocaleResolver.setCookieName("localceCookie");
        cookieLocaleResolver.setCookieMaxAge(3600);

        return cookieLocaleResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("locale");
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }

}
```

So i have LocaleChangeInterceptor, CookieLocaleResolver, MessageSource. I have `labels.properties` and `labels_en.properties`.

JSP:

```
Language : <a href="?locale=en">English</a>|<a href="?locale=ru">Russian</a>

<h2>
    lable.testLocale : <spring:message code="lable.testLocale" text="default text" />
</h2>

Current Locale : ${pageContext.response.locale}
```

When i click on link English, Russian, JSP reloading and Current Locale value on JSP shows Russian and English (depends on link). So locale changing successfully. Cookie with name `localceCookie` appears and it is contain ru or en value depends on chosen locale, but JSP value `label.testLocale` shows ONLY value for `en` locale and it does not changed. I looked up a lot of questions and most them were about localeInterceptor.

I tried Tomcat, Jetty, JBoss (now it is wildfly) applications servers. I tried different browsers. Also, i found [this tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/), project does not work, i made some changes like `@RequestMapping` for controller, but locale does not work in this example.

**UPDATE #1**

Accordingly to answer of @TechBreak i do the following:
1. Changed basenames of bundles and set default locale in CookieLocaleResolver

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource ret = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    ret.setBasenames("/WEB-INF/messages", "/WEB-INF/labels", "/WEB-INF/exceptions");
    ret.setDefaultEncoding(UTF8.name());
    return ret;
}
@Bean
public CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    Locale ruLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("ru").build();
    CookieLocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
    cookieLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(ruLocale);
    cookieLocaleResolver.setCookieName("localceCookie");
    cookieLocaleResolver.setCookieMaxAge(3600);
    return cookieLocaleResolver;
}
```

2. Move bundles to /WEB-INF/

Problem still exists.

**UPDATE #2**

Now my configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.example.*")
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private static final Charset UTF8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertiesBean() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("/assets/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/img/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setInterceptors(localeChangeInterceptor());
        return handlerMapping;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        OpenSessionInViewInterceptor sessionInViewInterceptor = new OpenSessionInViewInterceptor();
        sessionInViewInterceptor.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

//        registry.addWebRequestInterceptor(sessionInViewInterceptor);
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }


//    @Bean
//    public SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter simpleControllerHandlerAdapter() {
//        return new SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter();
//    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource ret = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        ret.setBasenames("/WEB-INF/labels");
        ret.setDefaultEncoding(UTF8.name());
        return ret;
    }

//    @Bean
//    public SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver() {
//        // TODO locale
//        Locale ruLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("ru").build();
//        SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
//        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(ruLocale);
//        return localeResolver;
//    }

    @Bean
    public CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        Locale ruLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("ru").build();
        CookieLocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        cookieLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(ruLocale);
        cookieLocaleResolver.setCookieName("localceCookie");
        cookieLocaleResolver.setCookieMaxAge(3600);

        return cookieLocaleResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        // TODO locale
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("locale");
        localeChangeInterceptor.setHttpMethods(HttpMethod.GET.name(), HttpMethod.POST.name());
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }
}
```

I try `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` but it is deprecated and [Spring says to use](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#new-in-3.1-handler-method-controller-processing) `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`, in both cases problem still exists. In label.properties i have Russian language and it is default locale, in label_en.properites English language. And Russian locale as default locale.

**FINAL CONFIGURATION**

This is important part of configuration

```
@Bean
public RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping() {
    RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
    handlerMapping.setInterceptors(localeChangeInterceptor());
    return handlerMapping;
}
```

And for default locale i made labels_ru.properties and for English locale i made labels.properties.

Comment: where is your labels_ru.properties? In it's absence it will go for default properties file.

Comment: src/main/Java/resources

Comment: It should not be under java. It should be in /resources parellel to java directory.

Comment: It is maven structure. U re right

Comment: @TechBreak I got right structure. Because my bundle are visible for JSP. It is src/main/resources

Comment: I think spring doesn't knows it is there, try full path instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are you using

> ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource

then you have to move your resource bundle files from current `src/main/resources` to resource directory of your `WEB-INF`.

Please read the documentation for : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html

It says to be able to reload they should be put into `WEB-INF` directories.

Also I see that you need to do configuration equivalent of following,

```
<bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

EDIT : Also make sure you have label_ru.properties file defined.

Comment: It does not help. Check my question please, i update it.

Comment: @dikkini can you just try first with single basename? ret.setBasenames("/WEB-INF/labels");

Comment: I am confused why you have added the local interceptor to hibernate related http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.html

Comment: i left only one bundle - lables - `ret.setBasenames("/WEB-INF/labels");` - spring message from other bundles setted to default text, because spring does not see them, but local changes does not work. About `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` i can tell you in chat or later in comments, when i resolve my current problem =)

Comment: @dikkini you seems to be missing localeChangeInterceptor registeration to handlers as i suggested as xml config. Try adding relevant config based on annotation.

Comment: In my question i shows configuration which containt Bean `public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {` and register it in Bean `public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {` using method `registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());`. Am i wrong?

Comment: DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping is deprecated class in Spring 4. I'll try now to do what u said.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128926/discussion-between-techbreak-and-dikkini).